# Typescript declaration for exported class instance

Tags: typescript

I'm currently creating my first declaration file for a foreign library(react-native-background-timer).
The library though has an default export I'm not sure how to declare in the index.d.ts file.

This is the default export of the library:

```
export default new BackgroundTimer();
```

I'm aware how to declare exported classes, but what's the best way to declare an exported class instance?

My first approach was:

```
declare class BackgroundTimer {
    [...]
}

declare const _BackgroundTimer: BackgroundTimer;
export default _BackgroundTimer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the way to declare `default export` that exports an instance, it's [documented on the breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#arbitrary-expressions-are-forbidden-in-export-assignments-in-ambient-contexts) page for TypeScript 2.6. Previously it was possible to do it in the declaration file in one line exactly as in the code

```
export default new BackgroundTimer();
```

but having arbitrary expressions in `export` was disallowed.

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that in the documentation